# Angular Watch on element show not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using an agular `$watch` to trigger an alert when the element become visible.

```
var scrollElement = "#hiddenObj";
$scope.$watch(function() { return $(scrollElement).is(':visible') }, function() {
     alert('hi);
});
```

Problem is that the alert is shown on page load though on page load, the element is hidden by default, and is shown only on click of some link.

Just to confirm my assumption, I put a break point just before this code, and in my console, I executed this code:

```
$(scrollElement).is(':visible')
```

and it return `false`. That confirmed the element is invisible on page load. I don't know why the alert is still displayed on page load. And when I click the link, and `scrollElement` actually becomes visible, nothing happens.

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: You should pass `(oldVal, newVal)` to your function and compare them first

Comment: @Phil On page load, the old value as confirmed from console is `false` for the expression `$(scrollElement).is(':visible')`, but when the element is shown, the console shows `true` for that. Ideally only at that stage the alert should be shown, because at that stage the `watchExpression` is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The watch listener callback will be executed whenever the `watchExpression` **changes**, not when it's `true/false`. So, when your page is loaded your `watchExpression` value will be `false` and the listener will be executed. To avoid that, you can check for the new value of your `watchExpression`:

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $(scrollElement).is(':visible') }, function(newVal) {
     if(newVal === true) {

        alert('Element showed');
    }     
});
```

The second problem is that the `watchExpression` is called on every call to [`$digest()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest). So, your click handler (to show/hide the element) must trigger a $digest cycle in order to evaluate the expression,  `ng-click` will be a good idea.

In your case the `watchExpression` is:

```
function() { return $(scrollElement).is(':visible') }
```

Answer (score 2):

this things should be coded in directives that change the scope variable like $scope.elemVisible

```
.directive("visible",function(){
return{
  restrict:"AE",
  scope:{yourVarName:'='},
  link:function(scope,elem,attrs){
    $(window).scroll(function(ev){//if you want to do something on scroll
      var vis=$(elem).is(':visible');
      scope.yourVarName=vis;
      scope.$apply();
    });
    $(someElement).bind('click',function(ev){// or if you want do something on click
      var vis=$(elem).is(':visible');
      scope.yourVarName=vis;
      scope.$apply();
    });
  }
}
})
```

html

```
<visible yourVarName="isVisible"/>
```

controller

```
$scope.$watch('isVisible',function(newVal,oldVal){...});
```